# Check if SKNode touches another SKNode

Tags: swift, touch, sknode

I am writing a game where I move nodes through touch functionality. When I am finished moving the specific node to the new location, I want to check if the node I have moved is lying over another existing node.

I have tried with collision checking by using

```
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
      ...
    }
```

but this does not work as this is not called when I move the SKNode.

Any ideas? I know this should be simple, but cannot find out how.

Comment: Have you set the [contactTestBitMask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/contactTestBitMask)?

Comment: Yes I have. I have set it to detect all contacts. But I don't think this is the solution as didBeginContact: does not call when I am using touch to move the node?

Comment: `didBeginContact` is called when two bodies first contact/collide with each other, not when you use touch to move.

Comment: Exactly. So I need to determine if two physics bodies are overlapping or not but cannot use didBeginContact:

Comment: Try `node1.intersectsNode(node2)`. It should return a boolean value - `true` for overlap and `false` for no overlap.

Comment: You could override `touchesMoved` and check for the intersection there as this is called repeatedly until the movement stops. This would be good for detecting for an overlap earlier. However you could also use `touchesEnded` if you wanted to only check for the overlap after lifting a finger.

Comment: Getting there! I can enumerate over the nodes to detect if there is a collision. Now the only issue is that node1.intersectsNode(node2) checks if the frames overlap. But in my instance I need to check overlap of the physics bodies which is quite a bit smaller surface. I make the check at touchesEnded as you suggest.

Comment: Hmm.. I would suggest going back to looking at your collision/contact model, since I can't see any reason why `didBeginContact` would not be working, as it should still be called, even when moving the object. Just make sure that you have set the `categoryBitMask`, `collisionBitMask` and `contactTestBitMask` for all the physics bodies. Also as you say the physics bodies are quite small, you may need to set the `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` property to true.

Comment: The problem is that the didBeginContact: only works when the physics are in use, i.e. when gravity is affecting the node. So it does also not fire when I move the node programatically through node.runAction( )

Comment: I could then suggest using a different method to move the node, such as via `touchesMoved`, in order to make use of the `didBeginContact` function which was made exactly for this :)